# Отсортировать список по заданному шаблону

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, list

Есть список:

```
countries = ['Другие страны', 'Казахстан', 'Международные', 'Россия', 'Таджикистан', 'Узбекистан']
```

`countries` может прийти по-разному, т.е. внутри может быть только одна страна или несколько. Порядок тоже может быть произвольным.

Мне нужно его отсортировать, чтобы получилось так:

```
countries = ['Казахстан', 'Россия', 'Таджикистан', 'Узбекистан', 'Другие страны', 'Международные']
```

Пример:
Получил такой список:

```
countries = ['Казахстан', 'Международные', 'Узбекистан', 'Таджикистан']
```

нужно отсортировать, чтобы получилось так:

```
countries = ['Казахстан', 'Таджикистан', 'Узбекистан', 'Международные']
```

Надеюсь, смог объяснить. Думал присвоить `id` каждой стране и сортировать по ним, но не знаю как.

Comment: по каким критериям идёт сортировка?

Comment: Не проще ли создать список элементов, которые НЕ должны сортироваться вместе со названиями стран?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если все элементы списка точно известны, то всё вообще просто:

```
countries_order = ['Казахстан', 'Россия', 'Таджикистан', 'Узбекистан', 'Другие страны', 'Международные']
countries = ['Казахстан', 'Международные', 'Узбекистан', 'Таджикистан']
countries.sort(key=lambda x: countries_order.index(x))
print(countries)

['Казахстан', 'Таджикистан', 'Узбекистан', 'Международные']
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
def country_sort(country):
    country_ids = {
        'Казахстан': 1,
        'Россия': 2,
        'Таджикистан': 3,
        'Узбекистан': 4,
        'Международные': 6
    }

    return country_ids[country] if country in country_ids.keys() else len(country_ids)


countries = ['Казахстан', 'Международные', 'Узбекистан', 'Таджикистан']

countries.sort(key=country_sort)

print(countries) 
# ['Казахстан', 'Таджикистан', 'Узбекистан', 'Международные']
```